# How to Mute Video with JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use following advertisement codes but I have problem to mute video after closing the video. When I close (additionally it closes after 20 seconds automatically) the advertisement, it plays the video in background and still there is sound. How can I mute video after I click SKIP AD button and when it closes automatically? I don't have knowledge about jQuery or JavaScript. Can you please modify my code and post the solution?

```html
<script>
  window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('closead').style.display='none';", 6000);
</script>
<div class="advertisement" id="closead">
  <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.sitename.com">
    <video id="dbx" style="object-fit: fill;" autoplay="" width="100%" height="100%">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </a>
  <button onfocus="this.blur();" class="closecss" style="position:absolute;bottom: 2px;right: 0px;z-index: 999;background: #32b02b;color: #fff;padding: 13px;border-radius: 4px;font-weight: bold;cursor: pointer;border: 1px solid #2b9825;box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 0 0 #299023, 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);" onclick="document.getElementById('closead').style.display='none';">SKIP AD</button>
</div>

<style>
  .advertisement {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Would it not make far more sense to completely remove the video element from the DOM when the skip button is clicked? That way you avoid the muting issue completely.

Comment: How can I do that? Sorry but I have not enough knowledge about these things.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this Yearmaz

As Enavar's answer says just put

> $("#dbx").prop('muted', true);

line in $(document).ready(function(){});

```css
.advertisement {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('closead').style.display='none';", 6000);
</script>
<div class="advertisement" id="closead">
  <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.sitename.com">
    <video id="dbx" style="object-fit: fill;" autoplay="" width="100%" height="100%">
      <source src="w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </a>
  <button onfocus="this.blur();" class="closecss" style="position:absolute;bottom: 2px;right: 0px;z-index: 999;background: #32b02b;color: #fff;padding: 13px;border-radius: 4px;font-weight: bold;cursor: pointer;border: 1px solid #2b9825;box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 0 0 #299023, 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);" onclick="document.getElementById('closead').style.display='none';MuteVideo()">SKIP AD</button>
</div>

<script>
  function MuteVideo(){
    $("#dbx").prop('muted', true);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But where do I need to add this code? 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#dbx").prop('muted', true);
});

Comment: check now just put that script tag below your <div class="advertisement" id="closead"> div and it should work!

Comment: Thank you. I am waiting. And can you please change video url to https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4

Comment: I tried this code but video starts with no sound. I don't want to mute when advertisement is active. I just want to mute it when I click to Skip Ad button.

Comment: i am not sure if we can do it or not

Comment: can you please try now i have added code that mute only when you press skip add button. and let me know if i am wrong

Answer (score 2):

If you can modify the upper script, this is a good way.

```html
<script>
 function removeVIdeo(videoId){
   var video = document.querySelector(videoId);
    video.muted = true;
  }
  
  window.setTimeout(function(){
   document.getElementById('closead').style.display='none';
    removeVIdeo('#dbx');
  },6000);
</script>
<div class="advertisement" id="closead">
  <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.sitename.com">
    <video id="dbx" style="object-fit: fill;" autoplay="" width="100%" height="100%">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </a>
  <button onfocus="this.blur();" class="closecss" style="position:absolute;bottom: 2px;right: 0px;z-index: 999;background: #32b02b;color: #fff;padding: 13px;border-radius: 4px;font-weight: bold;cursor: pointer;border: 1px solid #2b9825;box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 0 0 #299023, 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);" onclick="removeVIdeo('#dbx');">SKIP AD</button>
</div>

<style>
  .advertisement {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! It worked,too. I checked Dhaval Pankhaniya's answer as Solved because he posted first :) But your codes works without problem,too. Thanks you again.

Answer (score 0):

You can mute the video with mute attribute

```
jQuery("#dbx").prop('muted', true);
```

Comment: Can you modify my codes and add this code? Like I said, I have not knowledge about jQuery and Javascript :(

Comment: Change your script for this:
<script>
 window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('closead').style.display='none';document.getElementById('dbx').prop('muted',true);", 6000);
</script>

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I also edit SKIP AD button to onclick="document.getElementById('closead').style.display='none';document.getElementById('dbx').prop('muted',true);" . But it still same, it doesn't mute when I click to SKIP AD button.

Answer (score -1):

It will toggle between mute & unmute

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
$("video").click(function () {
    $(this).prop("muted", !$(this).prop("muted"));
});
```